# Interaction between a REPL and a program

Tags: java, scala, system-calls

What I am trying to do is create a program to act as an intercessor between the ***REPL*** (*lets say the scala repl*) and the ***user***. In other words, the user should type commands that instead of going directly to the REPL for execution, they are passed to the program, and then the program, after doing some editing gives it back to the REPL to execute, show the answer and so on.

What I have gotten so far is a simple interface using [scala.tools.jline.console.ConsoleReader](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs-2.10.1/jline/index.html#scala.tools.jline.console.ConsoleReader) to show a prompt, get the user input and show the results after calling *get_edited_data*

I also know that calling "scala".!< does the job quite nicely on its own.
What I can't wrap my mind around is how to connect them. I have already tried using [ProcessIO](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc2/scala/sys/process/ProcessIO.html) with no luck.

```
import java.io.PrintWriter
import scala.sys.process._
import scala.tools.jline.console.ConsoleReader

object Interfere {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val repl = "scala"
    val console = new ConsoleReader
    val prompt = "prompt> "
    console.setPrompt(prompt)
    val out = new PrintWriter(
      console.getTerminal.wrapOutIfNeeded(System.out)
    )
    var line = console.readLine
    while (!line.equals("bye")) {
      val res = get_edited_data(line)
      out.println(s"The answer: $res")
      out.flush()
      line = console.readLine
    }
  }
}
```

What I did with *ProcessIO* was something like below. But it does not make sense because it is not possible to give the current line as input, and generally have access to what is given to it.

```
Process(repl).run(
      new ProcessIO(
        stdin => line,
        stdout => out,
        stderr => out
      )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem recently. Laterly I use java.lang.Process to handle input and output.

A better choice is use [scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs-2.10.3/compiler/index.html#scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop) or [scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs-2.10.3/compiler/index.html#scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain) to build your REPL instead of creating another process.

[here](http://www.michaelpollmeier.com/create-your-custom-scala-repl/) is a example for ILoop.